# Is hawtio running on Karaf web console or on Jolokia bundled inside it in ServiceMix?

Tags: hawtio, apache-servicemix

I have installed hawtio in ServiceMix 7 and able to access web console.

Is hawtio running on Karaf web console or it uses Jolokia comes bundled inside it in ServiceMix 7?

Answer (score 1):

The `hawtio` feature installs `hawtio.war` to the Karaf runtime, which should then be provided by the OSGi HTTP service (Pax Web) in Karaf as is other war bundles.

`hawtio.war` embeds its own Jolokia library and uses its own Jolokia endpoint (http://localhost:8181/hawtio/jolokia) unless otherwise configured.

Comment: I don't see jolokia running in karaf feature nor hawtio.war inside the bundle  but able to access karaf web-console and access all components inside karaf. could see  Hawtio-core running in karaf. The hawtio web-console using jmx-hhtp bridge ?

Comment: How did you install hawtio?  Not `feature:repo-add hawtio 1.5.7` && `feature:install hawtio`?

Comment: yep.followed this ..feature:repo-add hawtio 1.5.7 && feature:install hawtio